# TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object when wrapping Pytorch Distributed Data Parallel in a class

Tags: python, multithreading, pytorch, spawn, multi-gpu

Here is a minimal code:

```
import threading
import torch

class DistributedMission:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.world_size = 8
    def start(self):
        torch.multiprocessing.spawn(self.worker, args=(), nprocs=self.world_size, join=True)
    def worker(self, rank:int):
        with self.lock:
            print(f'{rank} working...')
            print(f'{rank} done.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mission = DistributedMission()
    mission.start()
    print('All Done.')
```

It has an error at line `torch.multiprocessing.spawn(self.worker, args=(), nprocs=self.world_size, join=True)`: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object

Removing `self.lock`, this error disappear.

```
import threading
import torch

class DistributedMission:
    def __init__(self):
        self.world_size = 8
    def start(self):
        torch.multiprocessing.spawn(self.worker, args=(), nprocs=self.world_size, join=True)
    def worker(self, rank:int):
        print(f'{rank} working...')
        print(f'{rank} done.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mission = DistributedMission()
    mission.start()
    print('All Done.')
```

Or removing the wrapper class, the code also runs well:

```
import threading
import torch

lock = threading.Lock()
world_size = 8

def start():
    torch.multiprocessing.spawn(worker, args=(), nprocs=world_size, join=True)

def worker(rank:int):
    with lock:
        print(f'{rank} working...')
        print(f'{rank} done.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
    print('All Done.')
```

Why does this happen? Why does `torch.multiprocessing.spawn()`'s container class member matters?

I really need a wrapper class, and need a lock too so that the processes will not run in parallel for part of my code.

Comment: A `threading.Lock` is completely useless for serializing multi*process* code. Have you tried a `multiprocessing.Lock`? (I can't recall off-hand if those are picklable, but they're the only thing that's intended to actually work cross-process)

Comment: If you want to call `self.worker` as target in the subprocess, `self` must exist in the subprocess, too, and is copied by pickle.